# Looking for a workaround for SUMIFS + Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, sumifs

I'm trying to make a formula to calculate the total score (column C) per team per season between a date range.

As parameters for the formula, I have the team (Blue, Red, Yellow), the start and end dates and the season.

The problem I'm having is that to find out which team the person belongs to, I use Filter, which returns a table.
This works well with SUMIF, but doesn't allow me to add any additional conditions.
And if I try to replace it with SUMIFS, it only takes the first result from FILTER.

[Data sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOObj.png)

Here's the link to the file:[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TBOYb3ysBvApLrvJH5gOvvucw8c2P78d2F6qWcSZgMQ/edit#gid=0](https://stackoverflow.com)

With SUMIF I tried this:
`=arrayformula(SUM(SUMIF(A4:A10,FILTER(G4:G7,H4:H7=D15),C4:C10)))`
It almost works, but I can't add the rest of the conditions to the sum.

So I opted for SUMIFS:
`=SUMIFS(C4:C10, A4:A10,FILTER(G4:G7,H4:H7=D15),B4:B10,">="&F15,B4:B10,"<"&G15,D4:D10,E15)`
But SUMIFS only takes the first result from FILTER.

I'm struggling to find an alternative to this approach, I've started looking into the lambda and map combination but so far without success

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=sum(ifna(filter(C4:C10,D4:D10=E15,xlookup(A4:A10,G4:G7,H4:H7,)=D15,isbetween(B4:B10,F15,G15))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may try `MAP()` then `SUM()`.

```
=SUM(MAP(FILTER(G4:G7,H4:H7=D15),
LAMBDA(x,FILTER(C4:C10,A4:A10=x,B4:B10>=F15,B4:B10<=G15,D4:D10=E15))))
```

[image]

Comment: @rockinfreakshow Good suggestion. Then we have to apply few other tricks. Thank you!